# Can't delete department name in Laravel Blade table

Tags: html, laravel

From my index page, I can delete the student list of all data but I can't delete department names from my department table database. How can I fix this problem?

Delete function:

```php
public function delete($id)
{
    $department = Student::where('id', $id)->first();

    if($department != null){
        $department->delete();

        return Redirect()->route('department-index')->with('department_delete_success_msg', 'Department deleted successfully');
    }

    return Redirect()->route('department-index')->with('department_delete_success_msg','Something Went Wrong');
}
```

```php
Route::post('/department/delete/{id}', 'DepartmentController@delete')->name('department-delete');
```

```html
<tr>
  <td>{{ $number }}</td>
  <td>{{$department->department_name}}</td>
  <td>
    <form action="{{route('department-delete', $department->id)}}" method="post">
      @csrf
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="delete">Delete</button>
    </form>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Department Model:

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Department extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['department_name'];

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::Class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Because your delete function is deleting a student?

Comment: $department = Student::where('id', $id)->first(); You are retrieving department from student class?

Comment: @Anurat Chapanond After replacing $department  = Department::where('id', $id)->first();  its worked fine thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After replacing the Student to Department model name, now it works fine. It was my mistake.

```
$department = Department::where('id', $id)->first();
```